# No response to ping of specific size

Tags: networking, tcp, icmp

```
ping <anything> -s 473
```

does not receive a single reply.

```
ping <anything> -s 476
```

works, as well as

```
ping <anything> -s 472
```

but no size inbetween. What could be the reasons for this and what can I try to find the cause?

Comment: This happens for every request that is between 515 and 517 bytes long (on the wire), no matter what protocol. Wireshark shows lots of "TCP retransmission" for HTTP requests of this size.

Comment: I search my gateway with `route`, and after I ping it with no problem  `ping 192.168.1.1 -s 473`. I repeat with 472,476,515,517.. all ok. I repeat with a fixed `IP` on internet. No problem again. Which is your system, which the version of ping?

Comment: @Hastur I tried this and it turns out my UMTS USB stick is the culprit.

Comment: Write it as an answer, add the model of the USB stick the version of your system and of your ping command. It should help somebody else, and welcome on superuser.